# Find the expected value of symmetric random variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I have the following mock-up exam question:

> For a symmetric random variable X we know: $E[(X-1)^2] =10$ and
>   $E[(X-2)^2] = 6$. Find the expected value and variance.

Is the following method correct:
$$\begin{align} E[(X-1)^2] = 10 &\iff E[X^2]-E[2X]+1=10 \\ &\iff E[X^2] = 9 + E[2X] \end{align}  $$
$$\begin{align} E[(X-2)^2] = 6 &\iff E[X^2]-E[4X]+4=6 \\ &\iff E[X^2] = 2 + E[4X] \end{align}  $$
$$\begin{align} 9 + E[2X] = 2 + E[4X] &\iff 7 = 4E[X] - 2E[X] \\ &\iff \textbf{E[X] = 3.5} \end{align}  $$

Which results in the variance being: $Var[X] = 3.75$.

I don't have a solution for this, which is why I want to check it. It just seems to simple (and the property of symmetry is not used, there is second subquestion however).

Comment: what is symmetry? How does one define it for a random variable? :-)

Comment: @Math-fun $E[X-a] = E[a-X]$ ?

Comment: Your last equation means that $EX=a$. How does the symmetry help you with the solution? Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\color{red} {Var[X] =Var[X-k]} ,if \space \color{red} {k=constant}$$ so 
you can find $Var[(X-2)] =or Var[(X-1)] $ 
$$Var[X] = \mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x])^2]=\mathbb{E}[x^2]-\mathbb{E}[x]^2\\\to \\Var[X]=Var[X-1]=\mathbb{E}[(x-1)^2]-\mathbb{E}[x-1]^2=\\10-\mathbb{E}[x-1]^2=\\10-(\mathbb{E}[x]-1)^2=\\10-(3.5-1)^2=10-6.25=\\3.75$$ 
otherwise 
$$Var[X]=Var[X-2]=\mathbb{E}[(x-2)^2]-\mathbb{E}[x-2]^2=\\6-\mathbb{E}[x-2]^2=\\6-(\mathbb{E}[x]-2)^2=\\6-(3.5-2)^2=6-2.25=\\3.75$$

Comment: But I did it the other way around: finding E[X] and then using E[X] and E[X^2] to find Var[X], is that also correct?

Comment: @RobinHaveneers :Your way is correct to find expected value  , but I show you how to find $Var[X]$

Comment: Oh okay. I just used $Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, because one can find $E[X^2]$ from $E[X^2] = 9 + E[2X]$, using $E[2X] = 2E[X] = 2* 3.5 = 7$. Which results in  $E[X^2] = 16$ and thus $Var[X] = 16 - 3.5^2 = 3.75$